# Azure DocumentDB - Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

Using the c# .Net client SDK, I am calling the ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync method as follows:

```
sproc_response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<Document>(sproc_uri, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey( my_partition_key) }, doc_to_create );
```

The stored procedure code is as follows:

```
     sproc.Body = @"function( doc ) {

            var collection = getContext().getCollection();    

            var response = getContext().getResponse();    

            function create_doc_callback( err, doc_created, options ) {

               if(err) throw new Error('Error creating document: ' + err.message);                              

               response.setBody( doc_created );

            }

            collection.createDocument( collection.getSelfLink(), doc, {}, create_doc_callback );

        }";
```

This ALWAYS results in the following exception being thrown:

**Error creating document: Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted.**

Is there any documentation or example that clearly shows how to call a stored procedure using a partition key -- obviously, I am missing something!

Comment: What value is set for the partition key in `doc_to_create`. Is it possible that it differs from the value you're passing for partition key in the request options?

Comment: doc_to_create is a POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) and does not have a partition key property...  Does the collection.createDocument() method require a Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document object?  I have no idea as I am unable to find any DOCUMENTATION !

Comment: When you use a POCO it gets serialized and passed to Cosmos. There should be a property on the object that matches whatever you chose for your partition key which is how it knows where to place the object. If you don't specify one it goes into a special partition which is essentially undefined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create a partitioned collection in Cosmos you are required to pick a partition key which is a path in the JSON representation of your documents that will be used to place the document in the correct partition. If you're attempting to insert a document with no partition key it's going to get grouped in a special partition for documents with no partition key. You're specifying that the stored procedure should run within the context of a given partition but then trying to use it to insert a document into a different partition (the undefined one). Make sure that your POCO has a property on it that maps to the value you chose for the partition key on your collection.

You clearly know what partition you'd like to place the document in, as you're passing a value in RequestOptions for PartitionKey. Now ensure that your POCO includes this value on a property that matches the partition key you chose when you created your collection. The document will still have an auto generated Id if you do not provide one. Alternatively, you can just add the partition key to your document inside the Sproc as you're dealing with a dynamic JS object.

```
doc.partitionKey = my_partition_key
```

Comment: Hi Jesse -- thank-you for taking the time to explain.  When I persist a POCO object to DocumentDB, id use: response = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(col_uri, poco_obj );   Which works fine and returns a DocumentDB Document object per se.   If my partition key is the document id -- which is generated automatically, I would have expected that the call to collection.createDocument() (in the javascript) would behave the same way -- but it appears it does not.

Comment: Sproc can only operate on documents that have same value of partition key as the one in request options for execute sproc call. By default if you create a doc and don't provide an id, the id would be auto-generated (randomly). If your partition key is document id, auto-generated id would not match the one in request options. That's why the error. Would it be acceptable for your scenario that the doc to create would have id same as PK value from RequestOptions? You can set in JS: pass as 2nd parameter (pk) and set: doc.id = pk.

Comment: Michael -- my Sproc is CREATING the document via collection.createDocument() -- which is supposed to create a unique document Id.   When I create a document using the .net SDK, ie:  client.CreateDocumentAsync(col_uri, poco_obj ), the CreateDocumentAsync method generates a unique document Id -- which works fine -- I just cannot get a Sproc to create a document !!

Comment: There is no workaround for this. A sproc is only allowed to operate on documents inside of a given partition and you are mismatching the partitions. It's a simple matter of updating your POCO to include the appropriate value.

Comment: So to clarify -- there is NO way to create a documentDB document with an autogenerated Id from within a stored procedure? -- correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Id and PartitionKey are different things. If you do not specify an id one will be automatically generated for you. If you do not specify a Partition Key the document will be placed in a partition for undefined partition keys. A Sproc is not allowed to operate on docs outside of its partition. You MUST define a partition key on the document that matches the one you're passing to the Sproc

Comment: Jesse - thanks again for your patience -- my kingdom for an actual code example!  I do not specify an id -- because as you said, I expect one to be generated for me.   I have specified my partitionKey in the call to ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync -- so HOW do I specify the same partitionKey in the javascript portion?  Is there a way to extract the partitionKey via any of the "context" objects?  This is what I cannot find!

Comment: It would be so much easier if you would just extend your POCO to include the partition key. It's a simple matter of adding a string property and setting it before you pass it to the stored proc and everything will work exactly as you want

Comment: Well, I must still be doing something wrong as I tried to add the property "partitionKey" to the POCO which resulted in the same error.  Even tried "PartitionKey" - no luck.  Will continue to research .... ugh

Comment: What value did you choose as your partition key when you created the collection? Adding "partitionKey" to your POCO will only work if you chose "partitionKey" as the value you wanted to use. It has to match. That's the only way that Cosmos knows which partition to place your document in and is the fundamental way in which your database is able to scale.

Comment: The partition key is "/id" -- my understanding (and I am probably wrong again) is the partition key is the JSON path to the value to be used -- in my case I am trying to use the autogenerated Id as the partition key.

Comment: Ahh, I see where some of the confusion is coming from then. I cannot stress strongly enough that using id as your partition key is a poor design choice that will cripple your entire database as you will be limited to having a single document per partition. Recreate the collection and use something more appropriate. Review the documentation and video here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data as it will make some of these concepts more clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147995/discussion-between-jesse-carter-and-bdcoder).

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer nailed it. Unfortunately, I chased my tail a bit because my POCO property had a different case than the partition key.

Comment: I am also facing similar issue but in my document i have the partionkey id as property but am still getting the error ?

Comment: @ArjunMenon What is the partition key you've configured for your collection and how are you invoking the stored procedure?

Comment: PartitionKey is "id" and i am invoking via .Net SDK . StoredProcedureResponse<int?> scriptResult = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<int?>(selfLink, new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("id") }, eventObject);

Comment: You need to provide the value for the partition key. Not the name of it. Invoking it with "id" isn't valid provide the actual ID of the document

Comment: @JesseCarter ideally its a list of Guids.. So how can i have them. The SP is ideally for bulk insert

Comment: If your partition key is set to Id you basically have it set up to do one document per partition since there will be no overlaps. You can't do bulk insert with a sproc in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197223/discussion-between-arjun-menon-and-jesse-carter).