# Partition Key Error when running Stored Procedure

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert a single record into a collection with a partition key of `/newpart`

Just to make sure I'm interpreting what a partition key is, I'm assuming it is the value as shown here.

[image]

Within that collection I have a stored procedure called `createMyDocument` which contains

```
function createMyDocument(documentToCreate) {
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();

    var accepted = collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(),
          documentToCreate,
          function (err, documentCreated) {
              if (err) throw new Error('Error' + err.message);
              context.getResponse().setBody(documentCreated.id)
          });
    if (!accepted) return;
}
```

I call that via Python with:

```
config = {
    'ENDPOINT': 'deleted',
    'MASTERKEY': 'deleted',
    'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'database',
    'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'newup'
};

client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY'] ,'DisableSSLVerification' : 'true'  })
data = {"name":"Ben","age":30,"city":"New York"}
client.ExecuteStoredProcedure('dbs/database/colls/newup/sprocs/createMyDocument', data, {"partitionKey" : "/newpart"})
```

The error returned is
`Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted`

So I'm confused by the error message because the stored procedure is (to my understanding) stored within the collection with a partition key of `/newpart`. That's the same collection, and therefore the same partition key(?) that I am trying to insert the document into.
The error suggests otherwise however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When stored procedure is executed from client, RequestOptions specify the partition key, stored procedure will run in context of this partition and cannot operate (e.g. create) on docs that have different partition key value.

What you can do is to execute the stored procedure from client for each partition key. For instance, if stored procedure is to bulk-create documents, you can group the docs by partition key and send each group (can be done in parallel) to the stored procedure providing partition key value in RequestOptions. Would that be helpful?

You don't have to create stored procedure for each partition key, just create once without providing partition key.

According to your code, it seems that you're attempting to insert a document with no partition key and it's going to get grouped in a special partition for documents with no partition key.

In addition, you could refer to this thread: [Azure DocumentDB - Requests originating from scripts cannot reference partition keys other than the one for which client request was submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830792/azure-documentdb-requests-originating-from-scripts-cannot-reference-partition)

Hope it helps you.

**Update**

Please modify your code as below:

```
data = {"name":"Ben","age":30,"city":"New York","newpart":"11"}

client.ExecuteStoredProcedure('dbs/db/colls/newcoll/sprocs/createMyDocument', data , {"partitionKey": "11"})
```

Since your collection has a partitioning key set, the document you want to insert must have the partitioning key set, otherwise the database will not know which partition to place it in.

Of course, the partitioning key which is set in the document should also be consistent with the partitioning key which is set when the stored procedure executes, otherwise you will have the above issue. Because you can only manipulate the partitions you set up when you execute the stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry Jay, am still confused. Do I need to pass the partition key in the line `data = {"name":"Ben","age":30,"city":"New York"}` or in the line `client.ExecuteStoredProcedure('dbs/database/colls/newup/sprocs/createMyDocument', data, {"partitionKey" : "/newpart"})`? When I remove the partition key from the second line the error is that the partition key is not supplied. Are you able to modify my code to show me what you mean, or am I missing something fundamental in my understanding?

Comment: @BenMayo Sure! Please give me some time to update my answer about your code.

Comment: @BenMayo Hi,please see my update answer.Thanks! Any concern ,let me kown

Comment: @JayGong I tried this code for inserting data but it is giving the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @Anurag Hi,would you please provide more details about your scenario so that i could troubleshoot that?